# C++ dll works in C# console app however gives error in C# UWP app

Tags: c#, c++, dll, uwp, dependencies

I am getting following error when I try to use a function from DLL written in C++ in my C# **UWP App**. 
i can call same DLL in C# console application without any issues. 
I am not experienced in working with dll/dependencies. Really appreciate your help.

**ERROR in C# UWP App**::
***System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'WOOF.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'***

Below Program works without any issues.

```
//Program.cs file - single file C# console program that imports WOOF C++ DLL. Function 'FnWoof() only returns 42
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    namespace ConsoleAppCsharp1
    {
        class Program
        {

            [DllImport("WOOF", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

            static extern int fnWoof();


            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                int reply = fnWoof();
                Console.WriteLine(reply);
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");



            }
        }
    }
```

**UWP app code- does not work. get unable to load DLL error listed above :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;



namespace UWPapp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class UnitTests : Page
    {
        [DllImport("WOOF.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int fnWoof();
        public UnitTests()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void displayfromdll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int reply=fnWoof();

            result.Text = reply.ToString();


        }
    }
}
```

**Woof DLL code**

**Woof.h**

```
//Woof.h 
#ifdef WOOF_EXPORTS
#define WOOF_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define WOOF_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


extern "C" {
    WOOF_API int _cdecl fnWoof(void);
}
```

**Woof.cpp**

```
//Woof.cpp
    #include "pch.h"
    #include "framework.h"
    #include "Woof.h"




    // This is an example of an exported function.
    WOOF_API int fnWoof(void)
    {
        return 42;
    }
```

**dllmain.cpp**

```
//dllmain.cpp
#include "pch.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Reproducible example:   https://github.com/qaftab/Reproducible-example

Comment: presumably your dll has a dependency not available in UWP. Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick reply. https://github.com/qaftab/Reproducible-example

Comment: a [mre] needs to be in the question itself not in a link. Plus we'd need to know what `woof.dll` is as that's likely where the problem lies

Comment: Is the Woof.dll in same folder bin folder as your exe (check debug and release folders)?

Comment: i apologize in advance, this is first time i am using stackoverflow.. Woof and all code is already in the question. this is minimal code

Comment: @jdweng yes. it is in same folder as exe.

Comment: There is no dependencies in this case since it is not managed.  Open Solution explorer and check if dll is in the reference tab.  If it is then remove.  Since you are using DLLImport it is not managed.  Instead to make sure file gets into proper bin folder Add dll as Existing file and then browse to folder.  The dll should be seen where the other c# source files are located in Solution Explorer.  Then right click dll and select Copy Option If newer.

Comment: @jdweng THANKS ALOT. YOU SOLVED MY PROBLEM. i was having since two days. I was putting dll in bin/x64/Debug/    folder. when i add dll as existing item using solution explorer, it placed it in source code and on application launch, dll got copied to bin/x64/Debug/AppX. There was no way i could have figured it out that dll needs to goto AppX folder. Thanks again :)

Comment: I usually check the date of the exe in folder to see if the exe is being updated.  That is the clue that the file is not in the correct folder.  I asked on a different posting today to check the date.  I forgot to ask you the same.

Comment: @jdweng. Thats good idea. thanks for sharing. I ran into another problem, this time while moving code from C# console app to UWP C# app related to a device. Just posted another question. please let me know your thoughts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62311275/uwp-c-sharp-app-cannot-open-driver-for-device-connected-via-usb