# UWP C# app cannot open driver for device connected via USB

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, usb

I am trying to read data from a device that is connected via USB. **My app is UWP C#**. manufacturer of device supplied a .NET dll file. I can successfully open the driver, get driver config and read data with a C# console application **(console application works without any problems)**. However, same code does not work in UWP app. my code compiles and i am able to load dll. The code does nothing when device API's are called in UWP app.

i was thinking it may have something to do with specifying device capabilities in Package.appx.manifest file, therefore, i added following:
All examples i have seen online are for using windows APIs to interact with custom devices. However, i am using .dll file.

```
 <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap:Capability Name="removableStorage"/>
    <iot:Capability Name="lowLevelDevices"/>

    <DeviceCapability Name="usb">

      <Device Id="vidpid:1878 1321">
        <Function Type="name:vendorSpecific"/>
      </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>
```

I am not an expert in UWP or devices. Really looking for guidance on how to make my C# code + dll that works in C# console app to work in UWP App. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It not clear from you posting if you are using the Vendors USB driver.  Often the Microsoft USB Driver gets installed instead of Vendors driver.  Is the Device a Smart Card?  The dll says RemovableStorage. Did device come with a Certificate?  if so they may be an issue unlocking the storage device.  Try first reading device with c# console and then in UWP (do not try to unlock in UWP) to see if issue is with unlocking device.  Did c# app get built with same version Net?  Lots of people who have working 4.6 (or lower) app stopped working in Net 4.7 or higher due to encryption changes.

Comment: Note : The Device ID may be the crypto key that is used to unlock the device.   Make sure the dll is compatible with the Net version installed.

Comment: i am using vendors usb driver. in device manager, i can see device installed using vendor provided installation setup. this device is not storage media, this device is like a sensor/test equipment.

Comment: i updated C# console app .NET framework to 4.7.2 and console app still works. in console app, open_driver call opens the device configuration application on my PC (windows 10). UWP app is not able to do that.

Comment: Is the dll configuration correct?  Seems strange that the Capability says removable storage and the device is a sensor.  Do you think the sensor is encrypting?  A sensor can still store data in same manor as a removableStorage.  We use at work a high speed data collector were data is stored on the device in files.  Then we retrieve data using vendors API but over Ethernet instead of USB.

Comment: Check vendors documentation for open parameters.  The c# and UWP need to use same parameters for the open.  The question is if c# closed device when app exits.  You may try to kill c# in Task Manager.  Then run UWP without open.  I suspect something is not working with the unlocking of device.

Comment: sorry about confusion. above xaml is from package manifest file where i was trying to add custom usb device. it did not come from dll. vendor did not provide this file and it maybe wrong. So, i have copied code from C# console app, referenced .NET dll, there is no compile or runtime error in UWP however, UWP app is not able to open driver/talk to device.what do i need to do in addition to specifying device capability in manifest file before i can use functions in dll from UWP app?

Comment: update: i used function provided by dll to open_driver_config and it opened the driver configuration application installed on my PC. however that application reported an error " operating system not supported, update program to new version".. why would this happen when console app and UWP app are running on same operating system? is it something related to my target windows version or minimum target?

Comment: Are you running Windows 10?  UWP is windows 10.  Have you done clean builds?  Are you getting operating system not supported on c# or UWP?

Comment: i am running windows 10. I am getting operating system not supported in UWP app. C# console app runs without any issues.

Comment: May `supplied a .NET dll` does not support with UWP platform. We suggest you could make uwp app with desktop extension and load the data from extension then send the data to uwp client with appservice for more please search **UWP with Desktop Extension** blog.

Comment: @Nico. Thank you for suggestion. i need to read alot of data from device in milliseconds. What is best way to share data between extension and uwp app? is AppServiceConnection good for this purpose?

Comment: Yep, AppService is real time, you could use it to update real-time message.